# Does it make sense to think about steady state forecast error for Kalman filter with time-varying parameters?

Tags: time-series, smoothing, kalman-filter, exponential-smoothing

**The environment:** We have a  state equation:
$$
\xi_t =F\xi_{t-1} + v_t
$$
and a measurement equation
$$
y_t = H\xi_t + w_t
$$
with
$$
E\Bigg[\begin{pmatrix}v_t\\w_t\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_t'&w_t'\end{pmatrix}\Bigg ] = \begin{pmatrix}Q_t&0\\0&R\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $Q_t$ depending on time, $t$. We can then get that the forecast error (of $\xi_t$) of the time $t$ value predicted at $t-1$ is
$$
P_{t\vert t-1} = FP_{t-1\vert t-1}F' + Q_t
$$
and we can also get an equation for $P_{t\vert T}$

**The question:**
Does it make sense to think about a steady state of $P_{t\vert t-1}$, without knowing more about $Q_t$??

That is, $Q_t$ and $Q_{t+1}$ can be very different for all we know, so I don't see how $P_{t\vert t-1}$ can have steady state unless $P_{t-1\vert t-1}$ counterracts whatever changes in $Q_t$ there are, but I feel like $P_{t\vert t-1}$ being steady should imply that $P_{t-1\vert t-1}$ would be steady?

I'm looking for some explanation of how a steady state would work here. That is, **is it possible (and if so, how), to have a steady state if $Q_t$ does not converge to some constant?** Whether the answer uses math or not doesn't matter much to me, as long as I can understand the answer.